# integrating another package/module in my app

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the following module (https://github.com/intrbiz/hs110/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intrbiz/iot/hs110/HS110Client.java) in my app to control a TP-Link smart plug but cannot figure out how to get it done. I managed to add the dependencies for fasterxml/jackson dependencies but searching the dependencies for "com.intrbiz.iot" did not return any matches so I guess I need to copy and integrate those files locally but I am not sure how to do that (each function in the HS110Client.java file is defined in a separate .Java file (e.g. HS110Response.java, GetRealtime.java...etc.).

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!
Gaetano.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your trying to do but the link you provided is just a github link to some source code. I assume your trying to consume some API that was written and shared via github. You might want to import the entire project, jar it up and then include it in your projects dependencies?

Comment: That sounds like what I need to do but I don't know how to do it, can you spell the steps out for me?

Comment: Let me try to work it out, I'm sure there are articles already available to help me with the compilation and inclusion steps

Comment: I managed to jar up the project but not sure about the syntax to include it in the dependencies and where to store the JAR file (just in the root folder for my project?). Once that is sorted out, I will just need to invoke the functions within my app, right?

Also, I accidentally left the function declarations in my app and got a Build error message back saying that those functions should be declared in a JAVA file because they are public - can I still use the JAR file or do I need to use the individual JAVA files?

Comment: I ended up building the code into my app instead of importing the modules externally. The build process works mostly fine with one error being reported:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
 File1: C:\Users\Gaetano\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-(I had to truncate the contents to avoid exceeding the character limit...)

Comment: OK, I am one step further now: the build is successful, I was adding a second Android section in the gradle file which resulted in the above error being generated. After adding teh packagingOption-exclude section in the existing Android section, the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Nice work on jarring up the project. I cannot go into all the specific details on this post but I can try to guide you in the right direction from here. Try to view the .jar as an artifact that you will use in your codebase. 2 options from here are listed below, google each one as you will find many articles to help you figure it out.

1. Add the .jar file to your build path manually (usually something like right clicking your project in an IDE -> configure build path -> add dependencies)
2. If your using Maven (very common in todays development world) you can convert the .jar into an artifact and include it in your pom.xml

In my case I use maven, once you get the dependency in there your IDE might look something like below, note the "maven dependencies" section, it basically lists all the .jars in my project that I can consume.

Once you get the .jar in your project correctly the source code should become usable. Most IDE's use a hotkey as ctrl+shift+t (open type) that allows you to search for classes, if you can do that and see the classes from the .jar your built, you should be able to simply import them into any class your working on and use it directly.

Note: If you are using maven another thing you should check is if this project your consuming is already in the maven central repository, if it is, you can just add it to your pom.xml and your good to go.

Good luck and hope this helps!

[image]